# Swift Generic parameters and return types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, types

When working with Swift Generics, do the type placeholders all have to be the same types? The example below turns all type placeholders into a string type.  Is it possible for the parameter to be a string and the return type be an Int or do Generics work where each placeholder is the of the same type?

Here's the example:

```
func takeAndReturnSameThing<T>(t: T) -> T {
    return t
}

Let thing = takeAndReturnSameThing("howdy")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

The whole point of type parameters ("place holders") is that they consistently represent the same type.

If you want to represent multiple types generically, you introduce new type parameters.

```
func takeAndReturnADifferentThing<T, U>(t: T) -> U {
    return t.getU()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple generic types like this:

```
func takeAndReturnDifferentThing<T,U>(t:T) -> U { 
  return t.convertToU() // Assuming type T has this method.
}
```

Of course you should [constrain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186) both T and S to make sure that T can be converted to S.